# Elasticsearch JSON parse error

Tags: json, parsing, elasticsearch

Get the following data returned after querying an API. When trying to push to Elasticsearch keep getting a parse failure error. Running the following through jq play seems that the comma between each record might be causing the problem. Can I process the following with jq to remove just the comma between each record?

```
{
"id": "47",
"canUpdate": true,
"canDelete": true,
"canArchive": true,
"info": [
  {
    "problem_type": "PAN",
    "Category": "PAN"
  },
  {
    "status": 3,
    "Status": "Closed"
  },
  {
    "insert_time": 1466446314000,
    "Request time": "2016-06-20 14:11:54.0"
  }
]
},  < this comma causing parse failure? >
{
"id": "48",
"canUpdate": true,
"canDelete": true,
"canArchive": true,
"info": [
  {
    "problem_type": "PAN",
    "Category": "PAN"
  },
  {
    "status": 3,
    "Status": "Closed"
  },
  {
    "insert_time": 1466446314000,
    "Request time": "2016-06-20 14:11:54.0"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: The JSON you posted isn't a single JSON, but two.
As you can see the field `id` is written twice. You could split it into two separate JSON

Comment: It's an array of objects. You should use one object or [] for array

Comment: I've changed output to wrap the above with `{ "data": [ ] }` but still getting parse error when processing with Logstash.

Comment: One of the errors:
**[logstash.filters.json    ] Error parsing json {:source=>"message", :raw=>"      }", :exception=>#<LogStash::Json::ParserError: Unexpected close marker '}': expected ']'**

Comment: So I've changed the output to add [] making the entire thing an array however I'm still getting json parse error. I've run it through json lint and it does pass as valid json. I tried using "split" in my logstash configuration to split at "id" so that I would get separate documents for each id but that didn't work either.